# SQL Query for group by with multiple rules

Tags: sql, oracle10g, rdbms

I have a table called RXData which has 3 possible measurements called runFactors. Here is the structure of the table:

```
year,  compound, primary_runfactor sec_run_factor, qual_factor
 2015    RX1        0.12             0.22             1.3
 2015    RX1        0.33             0.22             1.3
 2015    RX1        0.12             0.22             1.3
 2016    RX2        0.12             0.22             1.4
 2016    RX2        0.12             0.22             1.4
 2016    RX2        0.12             0.22             1.6
 2016    RX2        0.12             0.22             1.7
```

The goal of the query is to group data by compound and year and then find the best runFactors. The rules for choosing the runFactors are as follows:

```
       Choose the maximum primary_run_factor of the group
         If there is a maximum value, select that row
         else if there is no maximum primary_run_factor
           Select the maximum sec_run_factor
          if there is a maximum sec_run_factor, select that row
          else if there is no maximum sec_run_factor
          then Select the maximum qual_factor
          if there is a maximum qual_factor, select that row
         else select a random qual_factor for the group
```

If there is no maximum qual_factor, select a random qual_factor for the group.

For example, a group arranged by year and compound RX1, for 2015 would have the following rows:

```
 2015    RX1        0.12             0.22             1.3
 2015    RX1        0.33             0.22             1.3
 2015    RX1        0.12             0.22             1.3
```

Based on the rules above, the maximum primary_run_factor for the group will be 0.33 so we choose row 2.

For the group, 2016 and compound RX2, the rows will be as follows:
          2016    RX2        0.12             0.22             1.4
          2016    RX2        0.12             0.22             1.4
          2016    RX2        0.12             0.22             1.6
          2016    RX2        0.12             0.22             1.7

The maximum  primary_run_factor is the same for all 4 rows, so we compare the maximum sec_run_factor. They are also the same. Next we compare the maximum qual_factor and find the maximum to be 1.7, so we choose row 4.   I am able to write the individual queries by using group by but putting it all together to use the rules specified is the challenge. I'd appreciate help in solving this problem. The queries below find the maximum runFactors for the cases. It's, putting it all together that's the problem.

```
 select compound,year,max(primary_run_factor)
 from RXData
 group by compound,year

 select compound,year,max(sec_run_factor)
 from RXData
 group by compound,year

 select compound,year,max(qual_factor)
 from RXData
 group by compound,year


   //Select a random row

   select year,compound,qual_factor from
   ( select year,compound,qual_factor from RXData
     order BY dbms_random.value
   ) as rand_row
   group by rand_row.year,rand_row.compound
   where rownum = 1
```

Comment: Please edit your question to tag your RDBMS. (sql-server, oracle, MySQL, etc). Also, you mentioned that you're able to write the individual queries - being that the "random aggregate" is arguably the trickiest part of this, I'd consider including it to cut out some work for those who choose to post a solution.

Comment: Will do, thank you.